# What does the movt mips instruction do?

Tags: architecture, mips

Like

`movt $t0, $v0, 0`

What does the above statement do?
It would be very helpful if you can explain it to me. I searched it on internet but couldn't find anything helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should've searched the official instruction set reference instead (*MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set*).

> `MOVT rd, rs, cc`
>
> **Purpose:**
> To test an FP condition code then conditionally move a GPR
>
> **Description:** `if cc = 1 then rd ← rs`
>
> If the floating point condition code specified by *CC* is one, then the contents of GPR *rs* are placed into GPR *rd*.
>
> **Operation:**
>
> ```
> if FPConditionCode(cc) = 1 then
>    GPR[rd] ← GPR[rs]
> endif
> ```